# tcpdf does not work with arabic characters at processmaker?

Tags: arabic, tcpdf, processmaker

I use processmaker v3.8.1 installed manual on windows server 2k16, processmaker use TCPDF v6.4.4
when I export file the html,doc work well but pdf characters look like squares or question mark

TCPDF not converting arabic characters

I tried download and instal font "arialuni" **not work**

set font in OutputDocument.php $pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 12) **not work **

upgread tcpdf to next ver **not work**

add " AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" to pmos.conf **not work**
use add font from processmaker command ./tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -i  {installation path}/shared/fonts/arialuni.ttf **not work**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO2Ul.png)

Comment: I'm sure I've implemented the guide correctly becuse it's showing in the fonts folder for  (TCPDF) and  user interface (HTML) for making the output document in procesmaker
here the code: --add font 
cd c:\opt\processmaker
processmaker documents-add-font arialuni.ttf
----------------
--convert font unicode
cd C:\opt\processmaker\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tools
php tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -i "C:\opt\processmaker\shared\fonts\arialuni.ttf"

Answer (score 1):

problem solved for me
1- add php font to tcpdf folder inside shared folder of processmaker
C:\opt\processmaker\shared\fonts\tcpdf
download form : https://github.com/akoweb/tcpdf/tree/master/fonts
2- add ttf font direct to fonts folder inside shared folder
C:\opt\processmaker\shared\fonts
download ttf font from any where
3- run processmaker command to add font to wysiwyg (HTML editor) in processmaker
cd c:\opt\processmaker
processmaker documents-add-font xkoodak.ttf
these font works (aealarabiya,xkoodak,xmitra,xnazanin,xtitre)
note : not all fonts work well like arialuni.ttf,sans
I'm not programer and professional may be my soluation be stuped but it's work for me.